# How to select an element that already has an on hover state with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, onhover

I want to add css styles with jquery to an element when another element is hover, the problem is this other element has a css hover effect already, how can i target this already hovered element with jquery?  Is a gallery of images that has an overlay color on hover, what i want to do is to add an opacity effect to a h3 tag when the gallery image is hover. This is the link: estudiodecimal.com/proyectos/
Here is some code i tried

```
$(".et_pb_gallery_image img").on('hover', function() {
        $("h3.et_pb_gallery_title").css("opacity", 1);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not targeting the h3 correctly. Since both the H3 and the img share a common parent, you can find the h3 through `closest()` and `find()`, like this. I added in a fadeIn and fadeOut rather than a show/hide.

```js
$(".et_pb_gallery_image img").hover(imgHover, imgHover)

function imgHover(e) {
  let o = $(this).closest('.et_pb_gallery_item').find("h3");
  if (e.type == 'mouseenter') o.fadeIn();
  else o.fadeOut()
}
```

```css
h3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='et_pb_gallery_item'>
  <div class='et_pb_gallery_image'>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300' />
  </div>
  <h3>Title</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i already figured it out, i used the following code: <script>
$(document).ready( function(){
  $(".et_pb_gallery").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".et_pb_gallery_title").css("opacity", 1);
  },function(){
 $(this).find(".et_pb_gallery_title").css("opacity", 0);  
  });
}); 
</script>